# Change output based on some parameters

Tags: php, oop, kohana

I wrote my own ecommerce website using kohana framework.

I decided change category view and it's logic based on "some" parameters.

For example,

```
if ($category->id == 'x') process with basic template and logic

if ($category->id == 'y') process with complex logic

if ($category->id == 'z') show some additional affiliate categories, show products with specific sku
```

I do not want to write many if-elseif-else conditions in my script.
I'm not friends with Object-oriented programming, but I've read that strategy pattern could help me.

Is strategy pattern good choice for solving my problem? If not, give me some clues.

Comment: Wow, it's rare to see Kohana questions today, as Kohana almost dead since everybody switched to Laravel/Yii/Zend. If you're not good at OOP, then maybe you could take existing e-comerce platform like Presta Shop or Open Cart?

Comment: Heard of switch statements?

Comment: For bad_boy: I use kohana because I can quickly customize my ecommerce website. I use prestashop also for my another project.

Comment: For Flosculus: Of course, I heard. But I prefer use oop instead of swich statements. Main reason is using different files to process different actions/logic. 

The code with if-else or switch statements are a little bit harder to maintain.

Comment: This is highly subjective.